# httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy call increases memory usage

Tags: go, memory-leaks

I am using these two lines of code to serve as a reverse proxy

```
reverseProxy:=httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
reverseProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
```

The problem I am seeing in testing is that after every 8 calls or so the memory usage of the app goes up by 0.2 MB. If I leave it alone for a while (many minutes) it goes back down.

I tried setting FlushInterval for the proxy, but that did not seem to make much difference.

If I comment out these two lines, then this memory leak doesn't happen, which means to me that I am missing some setting on the reverseProxy.

Comment: Are you creating a new reverse proxy on every request?

Comment: It’s not a memory leak if the memory use goes back down.

Comment: I am fetching it from a map. I am not recreating a new NewSingleHostReverseProxy for the same url.  I put these two lines because the bug in in this. I was thinking along the lines that there might be something like reverseProxy.close(), or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are creating a new reverse proxy for every request:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    reverseProxy:=httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
    reverseProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
})
```

When you should be reusing a single reverse proxy, either by doing

```
http.HandleFunc("/", httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url))
```

or

```
var reverseProxy = httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
http.HandleFunc("/", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.
    reverseProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
})
```